# JSTL tags not working in plain html file

Tags: html, jstl

I have plain HTML file and I want to include some JSTL tags in that, first I am trying whether this works.
But somehow JSTL tags are now showing value after rendering. Here is the code:

```
<html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
      <body>
       <c:set var="test" value="success" />
       <c:out value="${test}"/>
      </body>
</html>
```

And my web.xml has:

```
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

I have also added jstl-1.2.jar to my web-inf/lib folder.

Problem is I am not seeing anything on my html page. I am expecting to see "success". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the type .jsp?  If not, how did you expect the JSP engine to know that this had to be compiled into a servlet?

You also have to include the JSTL taglibs, right?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
```

Can't be a plain HTML file and expect it to work as a JSP.

Comment: No it is of type .html. The reason is I am using wicket framework for that page should be of type html. Is there any way I can use JSTL tags in html file?

Comment: I don't see how the JSP engine can know that it needs to compile a .html file into a servlet.

Comment: Looks like you need to be using Wicket tag libraries: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t60786.html

Answer (score 1):

Just include this in your web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've just tested in Tomcat 6.0.37